# Hot to refresh a WebView from another class

Tags: java, android, webview, refresh

How can I refresh a webview from another class?

**Webview class:**

```
WebView myWebView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plan1, container, false);
    myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wvheute);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("TEST URL");
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I want to refresh this webview from my mainactivity

```
public class Hauptfenster extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptfenster);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
        fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new fragment_plan1()).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hauptfenster, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_plan1) {

            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new fragment_plan1()).commit();

// I WANT THAT THE REFRESH HAPPENS HER :)

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_plan2) {

            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new fragment_plan2()).commit();


        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me??

Comment: is your `WebView` in another `Fragment` or Activity? Can you upload your full class of the `WebView` too?

Answer (score 0):

Save an instance of your other `Fragment`  and pass it to your `replace`

```
private fragment_plan1 fragment=new fragment_plan1();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptfenster);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
    fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

}
```

In your `WebView` fragment create a new method

```
public void refreshPage()
{
    myWebView.reload();
}
```

Call the method in your `Activity` when you want to

```
fragment.refreshPage();
```

Comment: Hallo thx for your help but i dont know what to do im not very good in java :) just started coding

Comment: @user5762515 well  i think my instructions are simple. Just copy the first code, add the second part of code to the fragment where you have the WebView and call `fragment.refreshPage()` in your activity whenever you want to refresh the page.

Comment: @user5762515 no replace your onCreate() method in your Activity class with that code

Comment: @user5762515 if you followed my instructions it should have worked. what error does it give you?